# Evaluate does not work in XPages (SSJS)

Tags: xpages

I have changed this Evaluate function into SSJS but It did not work :( 
funcDoc is NotesDocument.

LOTUSSCRIPT:
`Evaluate({@If(Ar1_Rates = ""; Ar1_Rates_temp; Ar1_Rates : Ar1_Rates_temp)},funcDoc)`

SSJS: 
`session.evaluate("@If(Ar = ""; Ar_temp; Ar : Ar_temp)",funcDoc)`

Comment: Please don't do this code.  Even with Knut's fix this is just crazy.  Take 15 minutes and use an actual JavaScript If then else block in your SSJS.  Very easy to google examples.  It will help you in the long run I promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
session.evaluate('@If(Ar = ""; Ar_temp; Ar : Ar_temp)',funcDoc)
```